# Python SQS boto unreliable or bad implementation?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-sqs

I got a box running on EC2 with 2 different python scripts that use 2 different SQS queues. My scripts have been working very good for the last week when all of the sudden one of them takes too long to pull messages from an SQS queue. Even when it manages to pull messages it pulls a lot of repeated messages. My 2 scripts use this same method:

```
def getMessages(self, n):
    '''returns n messages erasing them, mutliple of 10'''
    msgs=[]
    rs=self.queue.get_messages(10)
    if len(rs) < 1:
        return []
    count = 0
    while count < n or len(rs) < 10:
        msgs.extend(rs)
        rs=self.queue.get_messages(10)
        count += 10
    # delete pulled messages
    for msg in msgs:
        self.queue.delete_message(msg)

    return msgs
```

In this case self.queue is an instance of the following:

```
    self.conn = SQSConnection(SQS_ACCESS_KEY, SQS_SECRET_KEY)
    self.queue = self.conn.get_queue(queue_name)
```

My script uses the method getMessages() the following way:

```
while True:
    print 'Getting SQS messages'
    messages = sqs.getMessages(50)
    print 'Got %s messages' % len(messages)

    for msg in messages:
        do_something(msg)

    print 'Going to sleep'
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Now, my script just takes too long to pull the messages, it prints `Getting SQS messages` and sometimes stays there for hours. What makes it weirder is that if I open an ipython shell and do `getMessages(50)` it runs very fast and my other scripts works exactly the same but on a different queue and I have absolutely no problems with that.

What could possibly be wrong here, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have some bugs in your getMessages function in the while loop:
1. use `count += len(rs)`
2. The major bug: you don't need the

```
or len(rs) < 10
```

condition because SQS can get up to 10 messages and if your queue is full and each time you get 10 messages you'll have an infinite loop.

Also I think you should consider using `yield` statement to return the messages, process them and after they are processed, only then , remove them from Queue.

One more thing, the pythonic way to check `if len(rs) < 1:` is `if not rs:`